# dataview.rowfilter syntax error - missing operand mystery

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, dataview, rowfilter

Weird, weird error. I might just be codeblind, but:

```
    Dim dtdv As New DataView
    dtdv = dt.DefaultView
    dtdv.RowFilter = "Controller ID = 'PS2USB1'"
    XMLDGV.DataSource = dtdv
```

produces, at line 3:

`Missing operand after 'ID' operator.`

dt defined and correct. Column heading correct. Weird. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you have a white space in the Datatable column header. So, you have to enclose the Column name in the RowFilter within square brackets.

```
Dim dtdv As New DataView
dtdv = dt.DefaultView
dtdv.RowFilter = "[Controller ID] = 'PS2USB1'"
XMLDGV.DataSource = dtdv
```

Comment: Nailed it thanks, Insane. It may have been helpful for msdn to have put this somewhere in their DataView.RowFilter page! They do seem to miss some crucial stuff out.